# How to find the derived subgroup of $Q_8$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, quaternions, derived-subgroup

Given the group $Q_8=\{ \pm1, \pm i, \pm j, \pm k \}$ is there an easy way to find its derived subgroup?

I've tried by hand and this seems such a big task to do manually.

After this, by thinking a little bit I've gotten to the point where I've realized that if I got a subgroup of low enough order where its quotient group is abelian I could narrow the search for the derived group but still I fail to do so.

Thanks for the help in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The center $Z = \{\pm 1\}$ has order $2$, so the quotient group $Q_8/Z$ has order $4$ and thus is *abelian* (whether it's cyclic or not doesn't matter!), so all commutators in $Q_8$ become trivial in $Q_8/Z$.  Thus the derived subgroup $Q_8'$ has to be inside $Z$. Since $$
[i,j] = iji^{-1}j^{-1} = ij(-i)(-j) = ijij = kk = -1,
$$
we have $Z = \{\pm 1\} \subset Q_8'$. Hence $Q_8' = Z = \{\pm 1\}$.

Comment: Why does $Q_8/Z$ having order 4 mean its abelian?

Comment: All groups of order $4$ are abelian.  More generally, all groups of order $p^2$ for a prime $p$ are abelian.  Perhaps you have not yet seen this result, but in that case I am sure you will see it at some point in a first course on group theory. A direct proof in the case of groups of order $4$ is the first two paragraphs of the proof of Theorem 2.1 in https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/grouptheory/groupsorder4and6.pdf.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help

Answer (score 2):

First, since $Q_8$ is not abelian, the derived subgroup must be non-trivial. Since $Q_8$ has non-trivial abelian factor groups, the derived subgroup can't be all of $Q_8$.  Moreover, it's easy to see by brute force that $-1$ is an element of the derived subgroup.

Note that $\sigma:Q_8 \to Q_8$ defined by $\sigma(i)=j, \sigma(j)=k, \sigma(k)=i, \sigma(-1)=-1$ is an automorphism of $Q_8$.  If $i \in [Q_8, Q_8]$, then so is $j=\sigma(i)$.  But then $\langle -1, i, j \rangle= Q_8 \subseteq [Q_8, Q_8]$, which we just determined is impossible.  Thus, $i \notin [Q_8, Q_8]$.  Similarly, $j, k \notin [Q_8, Q_8]$, so $[Q_8, Q_8] = \{ 1, -1 \}$.

Answer (score 0):

For any prime $p$, there are 5 groups of order $p^3$, in which 3 is abelian and 2 is non-abelian. For non-abelian case, one can show that $Z(G)=[G,G]$ where $[G,G]=G'$ is commutator subgroup of $G$. Since $|G|=p³$, $Z(G)$ is non trivial (use class equation to show that center of a group of order $p^n$ is non-trivial). Now,$ |Z(G)|\neq p²,p³$ (why?) Therefore, $|Z(G)|=p$. Now, use the fact that for any group $G$, $G/G'$ is abelian and for any normal subgroup $H$ of $G$,  if $G/H$ is abelian then $G'\subseteq H$, in other words $G/G'$ is largest abelian quotient (this can be easily proven). Hence, $G'\subseteq Z(G)$ and $G'$ is non-trivial because $G$ is non-abelian. So, $Z(G)=G'$.

See this solution is very general in the sense that it tells us a nice result about non abelian group of order $p^3$. But for any group of arbitrary order we need to compute.

Comment: Tip: Write `$p^3$` for $p^3$.

Comment: I am actually writing from mobile so for simplicity I use p³ notation